# Гугл формы. Как удалить (скрыть) предупреждение от Гугл при размещении формы на сайте

Tags: iframe, google-forms

В Гугл-формы создал форму. Для размещения её на сайте, средствами гугл-форм сгенерировал html-код. Получилось следующего вида:

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfGLK2RenIKiCylCObpjeAVWfVFsdPdDgVM4GuYWqwLpo4NgQ/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="735" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Загрузка…</iframe>
```

На сайте форма разместилась. Здесь ОК.
Но внизу формы появилось предупреждение от Гугл, что они не имеют отношения, не использовать пароли  т.п.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как убрать или скрыть эти предупреждения?

Comment: Чем оно вам мешает? Если это действительно надо, используйте скрипты. Найдите ID этого элемента и удалите его. (`getElementById(...).remove()`)